# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status graphics.h

Tags: c++, bgi

I'm using the graphics.h library in Ubuntu 14
And I'm having trouble using this simple code:

```
#include <graphics.h>

main(){

    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");
    putpixel(25, 25, RED);
    closegraph();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And when I compile it, it gives me this error

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: did you forgot to link the lib ? (-L and -l options in gcc)

Comment: no i didn't forgot that i'm having a lot of troubles here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've installed all the necessary package,

change: `initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\\TC\\\BGI");`

to: `initgraph(&gd, &gm, NULL);`

and compile it with lgraph flag

example: filename is graph.cpp

```
g++ graph.cpp -o graph -lgraph
```

Comment: Thank you, good man, But it doesn't work i've tried that already. I'm still the same

Comment: you sure you've installed the necessary library ?
check this out (http://askubuntu.com/questions/525051/how-do-i-use-graphics-h-in-ubuntu)

Comment: yes, i have installed that library,But i still can't do it, thank you for helping me.

Comment: you are probably not able to link the library, how about linking it explicitly
try this `g++ graph.cpp -o graph /path/to/libgraph.a`